# A general question about spectral methods vs finite element methods

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis, finite-element-method

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_method) Wikipedia article:

> Spectral methods can be computationally less expensive and easier to implement than finite element methods; they shine best when high accuracy is sought in simple domains with smooth solutions. However, because of their global nature, the matrices associated with step computation are dense and computational efficiency will quickly suffer when there are many degrees of freedom (with some exceptions, for example if matrix applications can be written as Fourier transforms). For larger problems and nonsmooth solutions, finite elements will generally work better due to sparse matrices and better modelling of discontinuities and sharp bends.

I have only worked with finite elements, so I'm curious to know how spectral methods are "*computationally less expensive and easier to implement than finite element methods*". This is a bit of a surprise to me because matrices in the FEM are sparse, as opposed to the spectral matrices which are dense.

What are your opinions on this? Is there a textbook example of a comparison between the two?

Comment: This question is covered in basic NA textbooks, so probably not appropriate here. It would be perfectly reasonable to ask on scicomp.SE and will almost certainly get good answers there.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson The proofs of convergence for the Galerkin schemes, whether finite element or spectral, require some non-trivial machinery from Functional Analysis, especially when dealing with exotic domains where regularity theory of PDEs is non-trivial. This is why I asked the question here to get more "holistic" answer that focuses not only on the numerical parts.